# Swift | assigning nil to string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am writing an app using **Parse.com**.

```
func getContactsWithComplition(closure:() -> ())
{
    contactArray=[];
    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil)
    {
        var realtion: PFRelation=PFUser.currentUser()["contactsOfUser"] as PFRelation;
        var query: PFQuery=realtion.query() as PFQuery;
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (contactsArray:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
         if(error == nil)
         {

            for aContact in contactsArray
            {
            var cont=contact(phone: aContact["phoneNumber"] as String, firstName: aContact["name"] as String, lastName: aContact["familyName"] as String, adress: aContact["adress"] as String, email: aContact["email"] as String, role: aContact["role"] as String, note: aContact["note"] as String)
                contactArray.append(cont)

            }
            closure()

         }
        else
         {
            println(error);
            }
        })


    }
    else
    {
        println("suck")
    }
}
```

When the value of one of the sections is undefined, it returns **nil**, that can't be referenced as **String**.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by sections you mean the name, phone number etc.

If you want to substitute a default value in case of no value present, you can use the nil-coalescing operator:

```
//  assuming empty string is a reasonable substitute
let number = aContact["phoneNumber"] as? String ?? ""
```

Note the `?` used with `as?` - this way, if the value is ever not a string, it will fail gracefully (in fact, you will be forced to use `as` this way as of Swift 1.2).

You may need to fiddle around with parens to fix the precedence of `as` vs `??` depending on which version of Swift you're running.

P.S. if you are running Swift 1.2, you could probably eliminate some of the optional checking earlier on as:

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser(),
       relation = user["contactsOfUser"] as? PFRelation,
       query = relation.query() as? PFQuery
{
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { contactsArray, error in
        if let err = error {
            println(err)
        }
        else {
          // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just have started to learn swift few days ago, i am just trying to write code without using any documentation to see how easy is it to me, I will later on learn the full docomentation